# Tomcat Configuration window

Tags: tomcat, windows-services, tomcat5.5

copied pre-installed tomcat 5.5 version and want to add properties like initial memory pool , debugging option and more but i could not able to open tomcat5w application file from the installed folder. it is throwing error. I have added privileges in tomcat5w properties file also. But still facing same error. Please find the attached screenshot for reference.[image].

> the specified service does not exist as an installed service. Unable
>   to open the servuce 'tomcat5'

Please let me know how to resolve it. Thank you.

"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to register it as a windows service, since you just copied a pre-installed folder

please see [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html)

Comment: Is this process is same procedures for tomcat 5.5 also ?

Comment: changed link to reflect 5.5 version :)

Comment: tried using command   -  Install the service named 'Tomcat5'
C:\> service.bat install 'Tomcat5.5'  - But it is not working and said " 'service.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. ". Please let me know , how to do :(

Comment: i think service.bat is inside your tomcat folder. please open a command window as admin and then run it.